# Determine pixel coordinates of real world coordinates projected to image

Tags: opencv, math, perspective

I'm using OpenCV and python.

Let's assume a coordinate system where x axis is to the right, y to the top and z up.
I have a camera at a given position in UTM coordinates(x,y) (+ height (z)).
The camera faces north ('along' the y axis) and is rotated around the x axis by alpha degrees (down facing the surface/ground).

I also know the focal length, the pixel width, the image shape - width, height in pixels. I was able to calculate the real world boundary of a captured image.

So now I have an rectangular image with img_w times img_h pixel.
But the image that was taken has a perspective transformation. I was able to determine the real world corners of the image. I guess in a very clumsy way, but at least I did it completely on my own.

The image has the image corners 0,0 w,0 w,h 0,h.
The real world coordinates are not rectangular however due to the perspective transformation and are - as an example:

[image: Left side: Image, right side: the real world boundary given by the image]

Now my question is.
Given a real world coordinate in UTM and height, how do I calculate the pixel coordinate of the image given the information above?

Comment: 4 points and their images define a projective transformation of the plane. See [Finding the Transform matrix from 4 projected points (with Javascript)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/35416) for an approach to compute that transformation.

Comment: [implem example](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/)
long story short cv2.getPerspectiveTransform will get you the desired transform matrix

Comment: Well, both links aren't quite what I am looking for I guess (not sure though)

I have 3D-Coordinates that I have to map to my 2D-image. cv2.getPerspectiveTransform can't do that, or am I wrong?

I mean if I follow the "4 Point OpenCV ..."-Link, what am I supposed to do?
In the example he has 4 corners inside the image and transforms them to 
0,h w,h
0,0 w,0
But I have an already rectangular image in 2d (pixels) and the points in 3d (in meters, not pixel). So it is a 3d to 2d transformation with which parameters?